# Python - Dictionary isn't being registered in my code

Tags: python, database, passwords, accounts

I'm very new to Python and was testing myself on making a login and signup account database type thing (very basic) it's all text based.

Some reason, when I run the code and signup, it needs the accounts dictionary inside of signup(), but when I successfully create the account, it doesn't store the new account key and information in the accounts dictionary in def login() (hence why I put accounts dictionary in signup() too, because otherwise I get a error for accounts dictionary not existing) please help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8FnN.jpg - link to code (because pasting code into this website seems a bit buggy or I'm just stupid lol)

Here's what I've got:

```
def main(): 

    option = input("Login or sign up? L/S ")

    if option == "L":
        login()
    if option == "S":
        signup()
    else:
        print("Error - restart programm")


def login():

    accounts = {"user123": ["pass123"],
                "123user": ["123pass"], }

    loginUser = input("Enter username: ")
    loginPass = input("Enter password: ")

    if loginUser in (accounts):
        correct1 = 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

    if loginPass in (accounts[loginUser]):
        correct2 = 1
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")

    if correct1 and correct2 == 1:
        print("")
        print("Welcome to System")
        print("")

def signup():

        accounts = {"user123": ["pass123"],
                    "123user": ["123pass"], }

        signUser = input("Enter custom username: ")
        signPass = input("Enter custom password: ")

        accounts.update({signUser: [signPass]})

        main()

main()
```

Comment: Pasting code into this site isn't buggy, you just have to format it as code—select it and use the `{}` button, or manually add 4 spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need `accounts.update({signUser: [signPass]})`; just `accounts[signUser] = [signPass]`.

Comment: Also, unless you're trying to write code that's compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x, you don't need `print("")`, just `print()` is fine.

Comment: Thanks, these tips are top notch.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've got two different functions, `login` and `signup`, that each have their own local variables. The whole point of local variables is that they're only accessible within that function.

You either need to pass the values, or share the variables.

You can pass the values by using parameters (and `return` statements, but you don't need those for this example). Create `accounts` in the `main` function, then pass it to the other two functions; that way, they'll all have the same dictionary.

But you have another problem that you *also* have to fix: You should not be calling `main()` at the end of `login` and `signup`; just have them `return`, and put a *loop* in `main`. Otherwise, you're starting all over again each time; any local variables that got changed are going to go right back to their original values.

So:

```
def main(): 

    accounts = {"user123": ["pass123"],
                "123user": ["123pass"], }

    while True:
        option = input("Login or sign up? L/S ")
        if option == "L":
            login(accounts)
        if option == "S":
            signup(accounts)
        else:
            print("Error - restart programm")
            return

def login(accounts):

    print(accounts)

    loginUser = input("Enter username: ")
    loginPass = input("Enter password: ")

    # etc.

    if correct1 and correct2 == 1:
        print("")
        print("Welcome to System")
        print("")

def signup(accounts):

    signUser = input("Enter custom username: ")
    signPass = input("Enter custom password: ")

    accounts.update({signUser: [signPass]})

main()
```

---

I mentioned above that you need to "pass the values, or share the variables". What about the second one?

You can do this by creating global variables. (Or by creating a class, and using instance variables. Or by using nonlocal variables in a closure.) If you write `global accounts` at the start of all three functions, they'll all refer to the same `accounts` variable. But you still have to make sure not to keep reassigning it to the starting values over and over.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was well explained and very helpful, I had been working on trying to fix this all night and now it's! thank you, abarnert.

Answer (score 0):

The `accounts` dict in `signup()` is local to `signup()`, meaning it can only be seen within `signup()`. You are also creating a new `accounts` in `login()`, so even if the `signup()` `accounts` had global scope, all references to `accounts` in `login()` following the assignment would refer to its local `accounts` and not see changes made in `signup()`

Since `accounts` is a mutable type, you could pass it as an argument to  `signup()`. Changes made to `accounts` in `signup()` would then be visible in the calling scope, where you could then pass the updated `accounts` to `login()`.